# GNU 'ls' command not outputing the same over a pipe

Tags: shell, gnu, ls

When I execute the command `ls` on my system, I get the following output:

```
System:~ user# ls
asd  goodfile  testfile  this is a test file
```

However, when I pipe `ls` to another program (such as `cat` or `gawk`), the following is output:

```
System:~ user# ls | cat
asd
goodfile
testfile
this is a test file
```

How do I get `ls` to read the terminal size and output the same over a pipe as it does when printing directly to the terminal?

---

### This question has been solved.

Since I'm using bash, I used the following to achieve the desired output:

```
System:~ user# ls -C -w "$(tput cols)" | cat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm using bash, I used the following to achieve the desired output:

```
System:~ user# ls -C -w "$(tput cols)" | cat
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `ls -C` to get columnar output again.

When `ls` detects that its output isn't a terminal, it assumes that its output is being processed by some other process that wants to parse it, so it switches to `-1` (one-entry-per-line) mode to make parsing easier.  To make it format in columns as when it's outputting directly to a terminal, use `-C` to switch back to column mode.

(Note, you may also have to use `--color` if you care about color output, which is also normally suppressed by outputting to a pipe.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `-x` "list entries by lines instead of by columns" with possible `-w` "assume screen width instead of current value" is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

When the output goes to a pipe or non-terminal, the output format is like `ls -1`. If you want the columnar output, use `ls -C` instead.

The reason for the discrepancy is that it is usually easier to parse one-line-per-file output in shell scripts.